# toolbar previous and next button logic

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm using the following code to move to the next field using the UITextField delegate and also I'm adding a toolbar to the keyboard with the previous, next and ok buttons. The code is working fine.

Like you see the keyboard return button logic is pretty generic, using the UITextField tags, and that's good because I'm gonna use the piece of code all around. Now I will need to write the previous and next buttons logic, and I'm lost. Any ideas?

**UPDATE** (complete code, with some modifications, thanks to @8vius that spent some time with me in the chat to make it work):

```
//
// SigninViewController.m
//

#import "SigninViewController.h"

@implementation SigninViewController

@synthesize firstResponder = _firstResponder;
@synthesize toolbar;
@synthesize email;
@synthesize password;

- (void)move:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender {

    NSInteger tag = self.firstResponder.tag;

    if ([sender.title isEqualToString:@"Anterior"]) {
        tag -= 1;
    } else if ([sender.title isEqualToString:@"Próximo"]) {
        tag += 1;
    }

    UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];

    if (nextTextField && tag > 0) {
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [self.firstResponder resignFirstResponder];
        self.firstResponder = nil;
    }

}

- (void)ok:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    self.firstResponder = nil;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {
    self.firstResponder = textField;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {

    NSInteger tag = textField.tag + 1;

    UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];

    if (nextTextField) {
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        self.firstResponder = nil;
    }

    return NO;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.email.delegate = self;
    self.password.delegate = self;

    if (self.toolbar == nil)
    {
        self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];

        UIBarButtonItem* previous = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Anterior" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(move:)];
        UIBarButtonItem* next = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Próximo" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(move:)];
        UIBarButtonItem* space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace) target:nil action:nil];
        UIBarButtonItem* ok = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(ok:)];

        [self.toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:previous, next, space, ok, nil]];

        [self.toolbar setTranslucent:YES];
        [self.toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }

    for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [(UITextField*)view setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
        }
    }

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.email = nil;
    self.password = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple, when you load your view you set the `tag` property on your text fields depending on the order you want them in, then you have to just traverse the tag element on the fields:

```
- (void)toggleTextfield:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
  NSInteger nextTag = self.firstResponder.tag;
  if ([sender.title isEqualToString:@"Previous"] && nextTag > 1) {
    nextTag -= 1
  } else if ([sender.title isEqualToString:@"Next"]) {
    nextTag += 1;
  }

  UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:nextTag];
  if (nextTextField) {
    [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

And keep track of who is the first responder:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  self.firstResponder = textField;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  self.firstResponder = nil;
  return YES;
}
```

And when you load your view, you bind the buttons to the toggle action:

```
  UIBarButtonItem *previousButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Previous" 
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                    target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(toggleTextfield:)];
  UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" 
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                    target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(toggleTextfield:)];
```

In my case, for instance, I set up my text fields inside a table view, so in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I set the `tag` property to be the `row` of the `indexPath`.

**EDIT:** You have to set the `firstResponder` property for it to work.

In your .h file:

```
@property UIView *firstResponder
```

In your .m file:

```
@synthesize firstResponder = _firstResponder;
```

Comment: I'm very new to iOS, so I'm trying to learn (from) your code, but I'm gonna thank you already, I'm sure it works. Just one question: the keyboard return button will still work if I change my textFieldShouldReturn to your code?

Comment: Yes, it will work, this is the same setup I use in my own apps. You can still just use a hybrid of your code and mine, since you set the view to become the first responder and I don't. If you're very new I would also suggest checking out the CS193P course for iPhone and iPad Development from Stanford, you can find it on iTunes U, it's a great way to get started with a proper grasp on the iOS dev concepts.

Comment: This is the link to the course http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255.

Comment: I'm getting a error in NSInteger nextTag = self.firstResponder.tag;, It says I don't have the firstResponder in my class.

Comment: Oh yeah, you have to set the property up, sorry for missing that, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Oh, I got it, it's a UITextField that I need to syntetize.

Comment: Yep, you can have it be a UITextField, I set it to UIView because it's more generic, in case you have some other type of input field.

Comment: For some reason it's not working. Can we move to chat so I can paste my code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17843/discussion-between-8vius-and-lolol)