# keyboard hiding textfield

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a view controller with 7 textfields and I'm adding a toolbar to the keyboard (I don't know if it is important or not, but I'm using this [toolbar previous and next button logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831820/toolbar-previous-and-next-button-logic)). I think I have messed something up because when I jump to the next textfield the view controller is not rolling up, so the last 4 textfield are behind the keyboard while I type.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple discusses how to move content from behind the keyboard. See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7

Comment: I'm trying to implement the code but I don't a reference for the scrollview. How can I get it?

Comment: You need to add one if you aren't using one. Or you have to shift the frame of each text field when the keyboard appears.

Comment: So I need to add a scrollview? Damn tutorials. Let me try youtube.

Comment: That's one option. You would add all of the text fields to the scroll view.